# How do I prove this trigonometric integral inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, absolute-value, integral-inequality

If *f* is integrable and monotone on [*a*,*b*] then

$\left |\int^b_a f(x)\cos x\,dx\right | \le 2(|f(a)-f(b)|+|f(b)|).$

I've tried integration by parts and using the integral inequality property but I'm not sure how to piece everything together. I figure that I need to somehow use the fact that $|\sin x|\, \le 1$ but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreaciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We have

\begin{align}\left|\int_a^b f(x) \cos x\, dx \right|&= \left|\int_a^b [f(x) - f(b)]\cos x\, dx + \int_a^b f(b)\cos x\, dx\right|\\
&\le \left|\int_a^b [f(x) - f(b)]\cos x\, dx\right| + \left|\int_a^b f(b)\cos x\, dx\right|\\
&= |f(c) - f(b)|\left|\int_a^b \cos x\, dx\right| + |f(b)|\left|\int_a^b \cos x\, dx\right|\quad (\text{some $c\in (a,b)$})\\
&= (|f(c) - f(b)| + |f(b)|)\left|\int_a^b \cos x\, dx\right|\\
&= (|f(c) - f(b)| + |f(b)|)|\sin b - \sin a|\\
&\le 2(|f(a) - f(b)| + |f(b)|) \quad (\text{by montonicity of $f$}).
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know such a c exists? I follow everything else but that part.

Comment: @andrewkane2 it's because of the mean value theorem for integrals.

Comment: @andrewkane2 in case you're unaware, take a look [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Integrals) for the statement and proof.

Comment: This particular integral doesn't satisfy the conditions for MVT so I don't think we can utilize it. That's why I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @andrewkane2 so you're dealing with general Riemann integrable functions, not continuous functions?

Comment: I believe so. The only given information is that _f_ is monotone and integrable. In addition, in order to apply MVT _cos x_ would have to be non-negative. We could make _cos x_ non-negative by the integral absolute value inequality, but then all we would be able to do is then bound that integral by 1, which wouldn't help much in getting the result (at least from what I've tried).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only a small step away from solving the problem. Here is how I would do: First integrate by parts:
$$\left| \int_a^b f(x) \cos x \,dx \right|
=\left| f(b)\sin b -f(a) \sin (a) - \int_a^b f'(x) \sin \,x dx  \right| .$$

Then use the triangle inequality and additionally
$$\left| \int_a^b f'(x) \sin \,x dx  \right|
\leq \int_a^b |f'(x)| |\sin \,x| dx \leq \int_a^b |f'(x)|dx = \left| \int_a^b f'(x)\,dx\right|,$$
where the last step is true because $f$ is monotone.

I guess you can piece the rest together.

To get the inequality on the exact form in your question, you can use the fact that
$$f(b) \sin(b) -f(a) \sin(a) = f(b) (\sin b -\sin a) + [f(b)-f(a)] \sin a.$$

Comment: I just realized that I can't technically use integration by parts because the premise doesn't explicitly state _f_ is differentiable.