# Show that $\int_a^b \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) dx <3.$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Show that $$\int_a^b \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) dx <3$$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}.$

Here is my solution:

\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) dx&=\int_a^b \left(\sin x\cos \frac{1}{x}+\cos x\sin \frac{1}{x}\right) dx\\
&\le \int_a^b( \sin x+\cos x )dx\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_a^b \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)d\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
&\le2\sqrt{2}<3.
\end{align*}

But this seems to be incorrect, since we can not guarantee $\sin x,\cos x\ge 0$ in the first line.

Comment: remotely related but still might be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256881/how-to-prove-int-01-sinx-frac1x-dx-is-convergent?noredirect=1

Comment: You might need to do a little bit of casing ($0 < a < b < 1$, $0 < a < 1 < b$ maybe, and others) if you want to directly apply your argument. It might be salvageable, but the cases will probably get a bit taxing.

Comment: Just an observation: since $\sin(x+1/x)$ is an odd function, it is sufficient to only consider the case $0<a<b$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137373/how-do-i-prove-this-trigonometric-integral-inequality

Answer (score 10):

**Claim.** For any interval $I\subset\Bbb R$ we have $\int_I\sin(x+1/x)\,dx<3$.

*Proof:* Since $F(x)=\sin(x+1/x)$ is odd, the statement becomes $\int_a^bF(x)\,dx<3$ where $a,b>0$. By fixing $a$, we see by differentiation that the integral is optimised when $F(b)=0$. Similarly, we have $F(a)=0$, so $a,b$ are of the form $f_\pm(k)=(k\pi\pm\sqrt{(k\pi)^2-4})/2$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

When $a,b\in(0,f_-(1)]$, the sign of the integral alternates between consecutive roots, and the difference between these roots decreases as $k$ increases. Hence\begin{align}\int_{a=f_-(k)}^{b=f_-(\ell)_{\ell<k}}F(x)\,dx&<\sum_{n=2}^\infty(f_-(2n)-f_-(2n+1))\\&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{-\pi+\sqrt{(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4}-\sqrt{(2n)^2\pi^2-4}}2\\&<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\zeta(2)-1.\end{align} When $a,b\in[f_-(1),f_+(1)]$, we have $F(x)\le F(1)=\sin2$ so $$\int_{a=f_-(1)}^{b=f_+(1)}F(x)\,dx<(f_+(1)-f_-(1))\sin2=\sqrt{\pi^2-4}\sin2.$$ When $a,b\in[f_+(k),f_+(m)_{m>k}]$, letting $t=x+1/x$ yields $$\int_{a=f_+(k)}^{b=f_+(k+1)}F(x)\,dx=\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}p(t)\sin t\,dt$$ where $p(t)=1/(1-f_+(t/\pi)^{-2})$. Since $p(t)$ is strictly decreasing, we have $$\left|\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}p(t)\sin t\,dt\right|<\left|\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}p(t)\sin t\,dt\right|$$ for all $k$, with limit $\left|\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sin t\,dt\right|=2$ as $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}p(t)=1$. Thus $\int_IF(x)\,dx$ is bounded above by any consecutive combination of terms in the sequence $$\{\zeta(2)-1,\sqrt{\pi^2-4}\sin2,-2p(2\pi),2p(2\pi),-2p(4\pi),2p(4\pi),\cdots\},$$ so $$\int_I\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,dx<\max\left\{\zeta(2)-1+\sqrt{\pi^2-4}\sin2,2p(2\pi)\right\}<3.\tag*{$\square$}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Problem with the Solution in the Question**

In the answer presented in the question, there is the inequality
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^b\left[\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac1x\right)+\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right]\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&\le\int_a^b[\sin(x)+\cos(x)]\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\sqrt2\int_a^b\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
which, as suspected, is not true because cancellation can go on on the right side of the inequality, as wells as on the left side.

For example, consider the integral over $[\pi/2,\pi]$. Since $\sin(x)$ is decreasing for $x\in\left[\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right]$ and since $x+\frac1x\le x+\frac2\pi\lt x+\frac\pi4$, we have that $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\gt\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&\gt\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\sqrt2\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\gt\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$ on $[\pi/2,\pi]$
$\text{(2b)}$: $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$

Numerically, $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=0.496435$.

---

**A Possibly Better Approach**

For $n\ge1$, let $\alpha_n=\frac{n\pi+\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-4}}2$ be the $n^\text{th}$ zero of $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)$ above $1$, and $\beta_n=\frac{n\pi-\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-4}}2$ be the $n^\text{th}$ zero of $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)$ below $1$. Let us now compute the integrals between the zeros.

**Between $\boldsymbol{\beta_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha_1}$**: For $x\in[2,\pi]$, [$\frac{\sin(2)}{\pi-2}(\pi-x)\le\sin(x)\le\pi-x$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPvoJ.png). Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
I(C)
&=\int_{\beta_1}^{\alpha_1}\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3a}\\
&=\int_{\beta_1}^{\alpha_1}\left(\pi-x-\frac1x\right)\left[\frac{\sin(2)}{\pi-2},1\right]_\#\mathrm{d}x\tag{3b}\\
&=\left(\frac\pi2\sqrt{\pi^2-4}-2\log\left(\frac{\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2-4}}2\right)\right)\left[\frac{\sin(2)}{\pi-2},1\right]_\#\tag{3c}\\[6pt]
&=[1.401196175043,1.7591551592215]_\#\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: definition
$\text{(3b)}$: on $[\beta_1,\alpha_1]$, $2\le x+\frac1x\le\pi$,
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ so $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)=\left(\pi-x-\frac1x\right)\left[\frac{\sin(2)}{\pi-2},1\right]_\#$
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ where $[a,b]_\#$ represents a real number in $[a,b]$
$\text{(3c)}$: integrate and apply the [Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals)
$\text{(3d)}$: evaluate (Mathematica says the integral is $1.518576937887$)

**Between $\boldsymbol{\alpha_n}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha_{n+1}}$**: For $x\in[\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1}]$, $x+\frac1x\in[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$, so $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)$ does not change sign. Furthermore, $\frac1{1-1/x^2}\in\left[\frac{\alpha_{n+1}^2}{\alpha_{n+1}^2-1},\frac{\alpha_n^2}{\alpha_n^2-1}\right]$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
I(A_n)
&=\int_{\alpha_n}^{\alpha_{n+1}}\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4a}\\[3pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\int_{\alpha_n}^{\alpha_{n+1}}\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\frac{1-\frac1{x^2}}{\color{#090}{1-\frac1{x^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\tag{4b}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sin(u)\color{#090}{\left[\frac{\alpha_{n+1}^2}{\alpha_{n+1}^2-1},\frac{\alpha_n^2}{\alpha_n^2-1}\right]_\#}\mathrm{d}u}\tag{4c}\\
&=\color{#C00}{(-1)^n}\color{#090}{\left[\frac{\color{#C00}{2}\alpha_{n+1}^2}{\alpha_{n+1}^2-1},\frac{\color{#C00}{2}\alpha_n^2}{\alpha_n^2-1}\right]_\#}\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: definition
$\text{(4b)}$: multiply the integrand by $1$
$\text{(4c)}$: substitute $u=x+\frac1x$ and apply the bounds on $\frac1{1-1/x^2}$
$\text{(4d)}$: integrate and apply the Mean Value Theorem
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&\alpha_n&\frac{2\alpha_n^2}{\alpha_n^2-1}\\\hline
1&2.782160&2.296718\\
2&6.119781&2.054867\\
3&9.317452&2.023306\\
4&12.48628&2.012911\\
5&15.64404&2.008206
\end{array}\tag{4e}
$$
[image]

$A_n$ lies between $\alpha_n$ and $\alpha_{n+1}$. $|I(A_n)|$ lies in $\left[\frac{2\alpha_n^2}{\alpha_n^2-1},\frac{2\alpha_{n+1}^2}{\alpha_{n+1}^2-1}\right]$.

**Between $\boldsymbol{\beta_{n+1}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta_n}$**: For $x\in[\beta_{n+1},\beta_n]$, $x+\frac1x\in[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$, so $\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)$ does not change sign. Furthermore, $\frac1{1-1/x^2}\in\left[-\frac{\beta_n^2}{1-\beta_n^2},-\frac{\beta_{n+1}^2}{1-\beta_{n+1}^2}\right]$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
I(B_n)
&=\int_{\beta_{n+1}}^{\beta_n}\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\int_{\beta_{n+1}}^{\beta_n}\sin\left(x+\frac1x\right)\frac{1-\frac1{x^2}}{\color{#090}{1-\frac1{x^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\tag{5b}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sin(u)\color{#090}{\left[\frac{\beta_{n+1}^2}{1-\beta_{n+1}^2},\frac{\beta_n^2}{1-\beta_n^2}\right]_\#}\mathrm{d}u}\tag{5c}\\
&=\color{#C00}{(-1)^n}\color{#090}{\left[\frac{\color{#C00}{2}\beta_{n+1}^2}{1-\beta_{n+1}^2},\frac{\color{#C00}{2}\beta_n^2}{1-\beta_n^2}\right]_\#}\tag{5d}\\[3pt]
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: definition
$\text{(5b)}$: multiply the integrand by $1$
$\text{(5c)}$: substitute $u=x+\frac1x$ and apply the bounds on $\frac1{1-1/x^2}$
$\text{(5d)}$: integrate and apply the Mean Value Theorem
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&\beta_n&\frac{2\beta_n^2}{\beta_n^2-1}\\\hline
1&0.359433&0.296718\\
2&0.163405&0.054867\\
3&0.107325&0.023306\\
4&0.080088&0.012911\\
5&0.063922&0.008206
\end{array}\tag{5e}
$$
[image]

$B_n$ lies between $\beta_{n+1}$ and $\beta_n$. $|I(B_n)|$ lies in $\left[\frac{2\beta_{n+1}^2}{1-\beta_{n+1}^2},\frac{2\beta_n^2}{1-\beta_n^2}\right]$.

**Comparing the Areas**

Comparing the results of $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$, we see that
$$
|I(B_n)|\le|I(C)|\le|I(A_n)|\tag6
$$
Furthermore, $|I(A_n)|$ and $|I(B_n)|$ are decreasing, and the signs of $I(A_n)$ and $I(B_n)$ are $(-1)^n$. Thus, the largest the integral can be on any interval is $I(A_2)\le2.054867$ and the least the integral can be on any interval is $I(A_1)\ge-2.296718$ (this is just the reasoning behind the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) applied to the left and to the right).

Comment: Is there an error in this answer? It would be nice to know if the downvote means that something needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: Since $3$ is far from the optimal value,
it is not difficult to obtain a good enough simple estimate for the integral.
Actually, we can improve the estimate in Fact 1 via a similar argument.

---

*Alternative proof*:

Since $\sin (x + 1/x)$ is an odd function, it suffices to prove that,
for all $a, b > 0$,
$$\int_a^b \sin (x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d}x < 3.$$

*Fact 1*: Let $c > 0$. Then $|\int_1^c \sin (x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d} x | < 3/2$.

Using Fact 1, we have
$$\int_a^b \sin(x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d} x
= \int_a^1 \sin(x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d} x
+ \int_1^b \sin(x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d} x
< 3.$$

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

We give the following auxiliary results (Facts 2-3).

*Fact 2*: $0 \le 1 - \frac12 u^2 + \frac{1}{24}u^4 - \cos u \le \frac{1}{720}u^6$
for all $u > 0$.

*Fact 3*: $0 \le u - \frac16 u^3 + \frac{1}{120}u^5 - \sin u \le \frac{1}{5040}u^7$
for all $u > 0$.

Now, if $0 < c < 5/2$, then $|\int_1^c \sin (x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d} x |
\le |\int_1^c 1 \, \mathrm{d} x| \le |c - 1| < 3/2$.

If $c \ge 5/2$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_1^c \sin (x + 1/x)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 =\, & \int_1^c \left(\sin x \cos \frac{1}{x} + \cos x \sin \frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 =\, &\int_1^c \left(\sin x + \frac{\cos x}{x} - \frac{\sin x}{2x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\quad + \int_1^c \sin x \cdot  \frac{1}{24x^4}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\quad + \int_1^c \cos x \cdot \left(- \frac{1}{6x^3} + \frac{1}{120x^5}\right)\, \mathrm{d} x \\
 &\quad + \int_1^c (- \sin x) \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{24x^4} - \cos \frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\quad + \int_1^c (-\cos x) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{6x^3} + \frac{1}{120x^5} - \sin \frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 =\, & I_1 + I_2 + I_3 + I_4 + I_5.
\end{align*}

We have
\begin{align*}
 |I_2| &\le \int_1^\infty  \frac{1}{24x^4}\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{72}, \\
 |I_3| &\le \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{1}{6x^3} + \frac{1}{120x^5}\right)\mathrm{d} x = \frac{41}{480}, \\
 |I_4| &\le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{720x^6}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{3600}, \\
 |I_5| &\le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{5040x^7}\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{30240}
\end{align*}
where we have used Facts 2-3 in the last two inequalities.

Thus, we have $|I_2| + |I_3| + |I_4| + |I_5| < \frac{1}{10}$.

It suffices to prove that $|I_1| < \frac{7}{5}$.

First, we have
\begin{align*}
 I_1 &= \int_1^c \left(\sin x + \frac{\cos x}{x} - \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d} x + \int_1^c \frac{\sin x}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\le \left(- \cos x + \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\Big\vert_1^c + 
 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x \\
 &= \cos 1 - \sin 1 - \cos c + \frac{\sin c}{c} + \frac12\\
 &\le \cos 1 - \sin 1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{c^2}} + \frac12\\
 &\le \cos 1 - \sin 1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{(5/2)^2}} + \frac12\\
 &< 7/5.
\end{align*}

Second, we have
\begin{align*}
 I_1 &= \int_1^c \left(\sin x + \frac{\cos x}{x} - \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d} x + \int_1^c \frac{\sin x}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \cos 1 - \sin 1 - \cos c + \frac{\sin c}{c} + 
 \int_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x + 
 \int_{\pi/2}^{5/2} \frac{\sin x}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x + 
 \int_{5/2}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \cos 1 - \sin 1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{c^2}} + \int_1^{\pi/2}  \frac{\frac{2}{\pi}x}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x + 
 \int_{\pi/2}^{5/2} \frac{\sin x}{2(5/2)^2}\,\mathrm{d} x - 
 \int_{5/2}^\infty \frac{1}{2x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \cos 1 - \sin 1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{(5/2)^2}}
 + \frac{1}{\pi}\ln\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{2}{25}\cos \frac52 - \frac15\\
 &> -7/5
\end{align*}
where we have used $\sin x \ge \frac{2}{\pi}x$ for all $x \in [0, \pi/2]$.

We are done.

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer :

We use the triangle inequality so we want to show :

$$f(a,b)=\left|\int_{b}^{a}\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{\left(x\right)}\right)dx\right|+\left|\int_{b}^{a}\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{\left(x\right)}\right)dx\right|<3$$

With the inequality due to Ostrowski (see my last comment) we have $a,b\geq 4$:

$$f(a,b)\leq 2\left(\left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{\left(a+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\left(b+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\right|+\left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{\left(b+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\right|\right)+2\left(\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{\left(a\right)}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{\left(b\right)}\right)\right|+\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{\left(b\right)}\right)\right|\right)$$

The rest is smooth !

Comment: @TheSimpliFire What do you think about ?

Comment: Your bound is [still too weak](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ee4qspaax6).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No why ?Have you forgotten the constraint $a\geq 4$ and $b\geq 4$ ?

Comment: Ah okay then see [revised plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rdr4wxcrhr). You can relax it to $a\ge2.56$ and $b\ge4$ but this still doesn't amount to a proof.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No problem ! That's why it's a partial answer...Have you an idea to completes it ?

Comment: The expression looks horrendous to manually manipulate. I don't even want to try.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire If you speak about the last expression there is a big simplification at the end .As child's play :-).